# Начало изучения java

Tags: java

Скачал NetBeans, решил учить java 
Открыл, вижу такое

1. Java
2. Java FX
3. Java Web
4. Java EE
5. Java Card
6. Java ME

Что за обилие такое?) Начинаю учить после шарпа, где мне открыть что-то наподобие "win forms"?

Comment: @Fangog - попишите-ка пока в простом текстовом редакторе с компиляцией ручками, будет полезно, особенно вам

Comment: [Скринкасты по языку программирования Java](http://blog.devhelper.ru/skrinkasty-po-yazyku-programmirovaniya-java-nachalo/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Java** - начинаем отсюда
2. **Java FX** - пока забудьте, я думаю это скоро само по себе сдохнет так и не успев толком родиться.
3. **Java Web** - это кусочек Java EE
4. **Java EE** - нашефсё
5. **Java Card** - забудьте, если только не собираетесь заняться программированием банкоматных карточек
6. **Java ME** - тоже пока забудьте - звездный час технологии для мобильников прошел лет 5-6 назад.

Ну в общем стратегия изучения должна быть такая:

- Учим собсно язык
- Далее ставим веб сервачок типа GlassFish/Tomcat
- Навостряем ушки в сторону Java EE в части Servlet/JSP
- Далее смотрим в сторону Java Persistence API+Hibernate
- Потом начинаем осваивать фреймворки Struts/Spring и проч.

Comment: @Barmaley, зря вы так про fx. Её нативная реализация визуализации в связке с мощностью обычной javы довольно не дурно может себя проявить в умелых руках:)

Comment: На java же можно под андройд писать?

Comment: @stck дело не в мощности технологии, дело в конкурентном окружении. Java в плане десктоп/фронт-енд всегда была слаба - на моей памяти это одна из многочисленных попыток заявить себя в поле фронт-енда. Хотелось бы верить что все получится, но позвольте уж не поверить :)

Comment: @Fangog на java под андройд нельзя! А вот на Java под андроид можно!

Comment: @Barmaley, эх, не туда вы акцентировали внимание:) Я-то надеялся на то, что Вы ответите о связке, а не о мощности. Под мощностью имел ввиду сравнение javafx с javafx+java, но никак не `java as a desktop/front-end №1`;)